# If I move an object with my hand, will the object's temperature increase?

Tags: temperature

From my understanding, temperature is proportional to the average kinetic energy of particles.

If I move an object with my hand, then it will gain kinetic energy. Therefore, its' particles average kinetic energy will increase. Therefore, it's temperature will increase too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does temperature relate to the kinetic energy of molecules?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177038/)

Comment: No. Read through the answers in the identified duplicate by V.F.