# How can temperature be absolute if kinetic energy is relative?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, reference-frames, temperature, kinetic-theory

Kinetic energy is **relative** and depends upon the observer because velocity depends upon the frame of reference. However, we have an **absolute** temperature scale. How is this possible if temperature is the measure of (average) Kinetic energy ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relativity of temperature paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262382/)

Comment: See also:  [How does temperature relate to the kinetic energy of molecules?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177038/)