# Is the average speed for any nitrogen molecule 422 meters per second?

Tags: thermodynamics

Ok. TIL that a random moving particle of nitrogen in air moves at 422 meters per second.

Folks, that's 944 mph, and about 80 m/s faster than the speed of *sound*.

So is that correct?

Comment: Related, but not the answer. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96327/37364

Comment: One of the great moments of realisation for me was when I suddenly understood that *it must be at least as fast as the speed of sound*!

Comment: I mean like At least as fast, but why faster by so much?

Comment: @bleh because they aren't going in the same direction. If the sound goes at the speed of sound  through a bunch of molecules going in random directions then they must be faster than the straight line speed of sound

Comment: Presumably you mean the root-mean-square rather than the arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's mor eor less correct. Check out molecular [effusion](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Molecular+Effusion). A 1996 web page by [Michael Blaber](http://www.mikeblaber.org/oldwine/chm1045/notes/Gases/Diffuse/Gases09.htm) puts it at 515 m/s at 25°C.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the temperature of the molecule's surrounding (the higher the temperature, the higher the speed of the molecule). Around room temperature the **most probable** speed of a nitrogen molecule is around 420 m/s.

EDIT: It's also important to note that sound is transmitted through air with the collision of particles. So it makes sense that a nitrogen particle would travel faster than the speed of sound.

Comment: And *most probable* is not the same as *mean*. There is a non-symmetric distribution of speeds.