# If an ideal thermal flask containing ice starts moving does the ice melt?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

My physics teacher had told me that the kinetic energy generates heat..!
Hence a thermal flask in motion would have higher temperature than it originally started with..

I believed it until few minutes ago when it hit me that this is not a simple observation since everything we know and see are in motion but just not relatively..

So does the temperature inside the flask a relative qty to the motion? If so what equation can define the temperature for an ideal flask moving with a velocity v hypothetically?

Comment: The place to start is with [Why am I not burned by a strong wind?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/why-am-i-not-burned-by-a-strong-wind), which basically explains that the casul wording of your teacher's explanation has led you astray.

Comment: Are you familiar with the first law of thermodynamics?

Comment: @Chester Miller.., I am familiar.., with that... but my question definitely goes beyond that..

@ dmckee.., that's a start.., but doesn't cover the question in point.

Answer (score 0):

For a closed system, the first law of thermodynamics tells us that $$(\Delta U+\Delta KE+\Delta PE)=Q-W$$  If we do work to gradually accelerate the flask and ice, and no heat or change in elevation is involved, $$\Delta KE=-W$$Therefore, $\Delta U=0$, and no ice melts.  However, if the ice is now brought to a sudden stop, no work is involved, so $\Delta U=-\Delta KE$, and so some ice melts.

Comment: You mean to say that Ice melts on expense of loosing kinetic energy...,

but what if the flask never decelerates and keeps accelerating / maintains constant velocity...?

Further what happens if it is gradually stopped rather than abruptly as answered..., does the molten qty differ ?

Does the rate of change of energy from one form to another have a role in temperature since this is closed system?

Comment: If the flask never decelerates, the conversion of energy ceases.  If the flask is gradually stopped, then it does work on the ice to slow it down, and this work reduces the kinetic energy of the ice without dissipating any mechanical energy.  This kind of thing was already analyzed in freshman physics.  If the flask is rigid and stops abruptly, the kinetic energy of the ice is dissipated inside the flask, and converts to internal energy.  What other possibility is there?

Comment: You are now getting into the realms Joule's experiment to find the "Mechanical Equivalent of Heat". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equivalent_of_heat

Answer (score 0):

If ice inside the flask *moving at constant velocity* were to melt then a creature inside the system could tell whether it was moving or not. But motion is not absolute, hence it is not possible that ice would melt.

If the flask were accelerating, then for constituents of the system, this is equivalent to an applied uniform gravitational field. That is, in this case you must ask if ice would melt due to the action of a gravitational field. It wouldn't because gravitational field only causes a hydrostatic pressure gradient (in which pressure increases in the direction opposite to that of acceleration), and increasing vapor pressure on top of the ice inhibits melting (actually the opposite occurs).

All of this holds if you were to move the flask and its constituents as a whole, while not shaking it any way. In other words, any observer for whom the flask is temporarily at rest w.r.t. him/herself should perceive no other motion of the flask or its constituents. If this is not guaranteed, then you will end up doing work on the flask and its constituents and therefore the internal energy of the flask will increase (this does not necessarily mean temperature change; if phase transition is the only process occurring inside the flask then there will be no temperature change).

P.S. If the flask were to decelerate thereby losing its kinetic energy, then it is not necessary that it should appear as a gain internal energy of the flask. Some external agency might be sucking out the kinetic energy of the flask instead.