# Is internal energy frame-dependent?

Tags: thermodynamics, reference-frames, temperature, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

In the realm of kinetic theory of gases, the internal energy of gas is solely due to the sum of kinetic energies of all particles, since kinetic energy is frame dependent I was thinking whether a container having gas will heat up if I put it in a moving train, which is accelerating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is temperature a Lorentz invariant in relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83488/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't temperature frame dependent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90343/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out , that article would be sufficient

Comment: By the way, if the container of gas did increase in temperature due tovelocity it would  you would have a way to detect constant velocity  in violation of the principle of relativity.

Answer (score 2):

The total energy of the gas is the sum of its internal energy at the molecular level and its external energy at the macroscopic level.

The external kinetic energy is due to the velocity of the center of mass of the collection of molecules with respect to an external frame of reference. The internal kinetic energy does not depend on an external frame of reference.

The temperature of the container of gas will not increases due  to the velocity of the container.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Possibly promoting posting questions without checking for duplicates first?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Wasn’t aware of that responsibility. Can I find that policy somewhere?

Comment: I don't think its an actual policy. I guess its the same idea as to answering homework questions where the OP has not given any effort. Its promoting similar activity from other users who can say "Well this person's questions got an answer."

Comment: @AaronStevens OK in that case I will delete my answer.

Comment: It's up to you. If you think your answer is still useful, then I don't think one down vote should matter.

Comment: @BobD Yes, it's encouraged across the network to  do a brief dupe search before posting an answer, if you suspect that a question may have already been asked. See [this SO meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322096/4014959). Ideally, all the answers to a question should be in one place, where they can be voted on as a group, and to make it easier for future readers to find & compare them.