# How is energy transferred among particles of a body when we give some kinetic energy to it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, free-body-diagram

When we say a **body** is given kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, what do we mean by this?

**Is this energy transmitted to all the particles of the body uniformly?** If not, Where is this energy stored?

Comment: Basically you're asking why we don't include the energy of the motion of the container when doing thermodynamic calculation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't temperature frame dependent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90343/)

Comment: @Buraian what about the first part of the question ? Where is the kinetic energy stored ?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to make it more focused empahsizing on where it's stored only. @Ankit

Comment: And I think that you should remove out the last part about the temperature thing because it is discussed in that stack post I commented and linked ones. Or if you don't think that those explanation was satisfactory, then you should pick out those point and put it in this question

Comment: @Ankit This is a good Q and even I used to have confusions in it. My recommendation is that you just check the derivation of P.E and K.E from F.S. You will get your answer.