# Why is temperature a " Frame independent " quantity?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, kinetic-theory

The fact that if we place a jar full of gas in a moving train won't change its temperature , and that the temperature isn't really affected by the motion ( even though kinetic energy of gas molecules is increased ) is something I am confused with.

Temperature is related to motion of the molecules and it's kinetic energy and motion is frame dependent,
So why is temperature frame independent? And does depend on the systematic motion of molecules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't temperature frame dependent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90343/) And links therein