# Heat energy in special theory of relativity

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, invariants

Is heat energy invariant under Lorentz transformation? If so then how?

Comment: No, the energy density is the 00 component of the stress-energy tensor. Would post an answer except I don't know enough to elaborate...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is temperature a Lorentz invariant in relativity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83488/)