# Temperature of an object at very high speed?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, relativity

What happens to the inherent temperature of an object seen from a stationary frame of reference when it travels nearly at speed of light in vacuum?

As the mass increases heat will have to be distributed more and temperature reduces?

Comment: The mass of a fast moving object doesn't increase. I assume you're thinking of the *relativistic mass* but this is not a useful concept and is no longer used.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Yes, relativistic mass. Why is it no longer used?  Didn't know about that.

Comment: See [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed). A search for [relativistic mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=relativistic+mass) will find you lots and lots of related posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is temperature a Lorentz invariant in relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83488)