# Can relativity apply to temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, temperature, entropy, observers

Given a stationary observer and a moving one. One would see the particle in a system of gas moving faster than the other would. Does that mean the particles have more kinetic energy and thus higher temperature? If so what does that say about entropy in different frames of references?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83488/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thank you @Qmechanic Yes that is exactly what I was looking for!